# Information sharing in group

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems

I have a group with n members. These are distributed members. It is basically a group chat. A new member is added to the group and the existing members are informed about this.

Now I want the new member to obtain some information about the group that the existing members all know. This could be the name of the group.
There is no centralised place where this information can be obtained.
Also, messages sent in the group will go to every member of the group.

My current implementation is that all the existing members send the information to the new member, but this is causing everyone to receive many messages. I would like the number of messages to be as low as possible, which I guess would mean that one message should be enough.

I cannot just make the member with the lowest ID be the one to send the message, as that person might not be online.

So, is this problem, a problem with a known solution? And what might that be?

I hope the explanation makes sense.

Comment: The model doesn't have enough details to answer the question correctly.  One suggestion is that every member of the group draws a random number from $1$ to, let's say $n^2$.  Then they wait for that many seconds before they send a message.  They don't send a message if someone else already sent one.

Comment: "the existing members are informed about this": how, if there is no centralized place ?

Comment: Can't you get the lowest ID of the online persons ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No users knows who is online.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There is a centralised server, but it only keeps track of members, not this "other" information.

Comment: @PålGD That would reduce the number of messages. Maybe not to zero, but better than my "solution".

Comment: Can you also send messages peer to peer, or do they always have to be broadcasted?

Comment: How about tokens with timeouts? Rotate the token after a certain period and the user if online can send the message.

Comment: What is the expected time to transmit a message?

Comment: So the server can arrange these transfers. Or the server could act as a group member.

Comment: @nirshahar only broadcast

Comment: @PålGD Usually quite fast < one second, but occasionally slower.

Comment: @YvesDaoust server is quite limited, can broadcast messages, but does not have knowledge about the problem as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that the expected time a message takes in transit is $t$, and typically $ t \leq 100\;\text{ms}$.

Your group has $n$ members.  When a new member enters the group, each existing member draws an integer $w_i$ at random from $[1, q \cdot n]$ for some $q \geq 1$.
Then each member waits for $t \cdot w_i \; \text{ms}$.  If no message has been sent to the group, then that member sends a message.

According to the answer by Raskolnikov on [maths.sx](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4587636/55346), the probability that more than one member will be chosen to send a message is
$$
1- \frac{1}{
q (e^{1/q} - 1)
},
$$
which interestingly does not depend on $n$.

If you choose $q$ to be large (e.g. 100), then the probability that two members will be chosen to send the message is very small (<0.5%), but the waiting time will be larger.  If you choose $q$ to be small (e.g. 5), the probability will be larger, but still less than 10%, and the waiting time will be much smaller.

Ps., compute the probability of a collision using

```python
def prob_coll(q):
    return 1 - (1 / (q * (math.e ** (1 / q) - 1)))
```